# What are the names of the Current Lords of Terra?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In the most current timeline of the W40k universe it is M42.
Of the 12 Lords that are supposed to rule the Empire of Man I know only the name of one, Decius XXIII is Ecclesiarch of the Adeptus Ministorum as of 945.M41.

What are the names of the rest of the Lords?

Most current names are preferable (if nothing else can be found) as we know that with juvenant treatmants etc. these guys can prolong their lives considerably.

Ecclesiarch: Decius XXIII

**EDIT**

The second name that is now known is Roboute Guilliman who again holds his own original title as Lord Commander.

Lord Commander: Roboute Guilliman

Comment: [This 1d4chan entry](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/High_Lords_of_Terra) is pretty good, it's worth a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the topic, I found this:

> Determining who will hold the position of High Lord has resulted in millennia of political intrigue between the various bureaucracies seeking to increase their power. However, some organisations are so powerful, so fundamentally important to the Imperium, that their position on the Council is considered sacrosanct. For this reason the following nine offices are almost always represented as High Lords:
>
> - The Master of the Administratum
> - The Inquisitorial Representative
> - The Ecclesiarch of the Adeptus Ministorum
> - The Fabricator-General of the Adeptus Mechanicus
> - The Grand Provost Marshal of the Adeptus Arbites
> - The Paternoval Envoy of the Navigators
> - The Master of the Astronomican
> - The Grand Master of the Officio Assassinorum
> - The Master of the Adeptus Astra Telepathica
>
> The remaining three positions are most likely to be filled from among the 
>   following powerful leaders:
>
> - Lord Commander of Segmentum Solar
> - Lord Commander Militant of the Imperial Guard
> - Cardinal(s) of the Holy Synod of Terra
> - The Abbess of the Adepta Sororitas
> - Captain-General of the Adeptus Custodes
> - The Chancellor of the Estate Imperium
> - The Speaker for the Chartist Captains
> - Lord High Admiral of the Imperial Navy

Sadly apart from the ones that you have already named, only two other names are known:

- The Last Fabricator-General: **Gastaph Hediatrix**
- The Last Captain-General of the Adeptus Custode: **Beyreuth**

But these names are indicative because it is not known whether they are still active or not. (M36)

On the rest of the name, I have not been able to find anything in reliable sources.

**SOURCE:**

- Battlefleet Gothic 41st Millennium, pg. 86 //
- Codex: Assassins (2nd Edition), pg. 24 //
- Codex: Chaos Space Marines (3rd Edition, 2nd Codex), pg. 7 //
- Codex: Gray Knights (5th Edition) //
- Codex: Imperialis (2nd Edition) by Rick Priestley, pp. 13-14 //
- Codex: Orks (4th Edition), p. 92 //
- Codex: Sisters of Battle (2nd Edition), pp. 5, 13, 16 //
- Codex: Space Marines (6th Edition) (Digital Edition), pp. 36, 85, 100, //
- Codex: Ultramarines (2nd Edition), pg. Referring to Fig. //
- Codex: Witchhunters (3rd Edition), pg. Four. Five //
- Dark Heresy: Blood of Martyrs (RPG), p. 9, 12, 14, 17, 22 //
- Dark Heresy: Daemon Hunter (RPG), pg. 7 //
- Deathwatch: Core Rulebook (RPG), pp. 12, 285, 297, 323, 331-332 //
- Deathwatch: Rites of Battle (RPG), pp. 13-16, 38, 54, 65, 98, 247 //
- Deathwatch: The Achilus Assault (RPG), pp. 12, 14-15, 22, 102, 110, 119 //
- Horus Heresy: Visions of War //
- Warhammer 40,000: Rulebook (Digital Edition) (7th Edition), pp. 270, 275-278, 284, 286, 314, 323, 331, 335, 374, 381-382, 385, 387, 540-542 //
- Warhammer 40,000: Rulebook (6th Edition), pg. 403 //
- Warhammer 40,000: Rulebook (5th Edition), pg. 124 //
- Warhammer 40,000: Rulebook (4th Edition), pp. 9-10, 92 //
- White Dwarf 293 (UK), "Index Malleus: The Blood Pact", p. 57 //
- White Dwarf 140 (UK), "Space Fleet: Additional Background, Rules, Data Cards & Counters", p. fifty //
- False Gods (Novel) by Graham McNeill //
- Legion of the Damned (Novel) by Rob Sanders, pg. eleven //
- Wolfblade (Novel) by William King, pp. 32, 37, 70, 104 //

***PS:*** Here I would miss the information of the last books but as they are about the heresy of Horus I don't know if they would contribute with anything ...